# I have an error that states that I have a loop without a do

Tags: loops, vbscript

Maybe I am not seeing it but I really believe that I have a do for ever loop! Can someone help? I started with an initial do so I could give the user  the ability to use the code again. Thanks for any help guys.

Code:

```
'Written by Douglas Howe
Option Explicit
Dim colorPicOne, colorPicTwo, tryAgain

'initial do
do
  'first prompt
  do
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Pick a primary color (i.e blue, red, or yellow): "
    colorPicOne = lcase(wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
    if colorPicOne <> "blue" and colorPicOne <> "red" and colorPicOne <> "yellow" then
      Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Not a primary color! Please pick another color: "
    else 
      exit do
    end if
  loop while colorPicOne <> "blue" OR colorPicOne <> "red" or colorPicOne <> "yellow"

  'second prompt
  do
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Pick another primary color (i.e blue, red, or yellow): "
    colorPicTwo = lcase(wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
    if colorPicTwo <> "blue" and colorPicTwo <> "red" and colorPicTwo <> "yellow" then
      Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Not a primary color! Please pick another color: "
    else
      exit do
    end if
  loop while colorPicTwo <> "blue" OR colorPicTwo <> "red" or colorPicTwo <> "yellow"

  if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "blue" then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
  else
    if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
      Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
  end if


  if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "yellow" then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is orange!"
  else
    if colorPicOne = "yellow" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
      Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is orange!"
  end if

  if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo = "yellow" then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is green!"
  else
    if colorPicOne = "yellow" and colorPicTwo ="blue" then
      Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is green!"
  end if

  Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Would you like to try again? (yes or no) :"
  tryAgain =lcase(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)

  if tryAgain = "no" then
    Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Have a nice day"
    exit do
    if tryAgain = "yes" then
      Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Ok!"
    else 
      Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Sorry, you gave an invalid response. Good Bye!"
      exit do
    end if
  end if
loop while tryAgain = "yes"
```

My error states that I have a `loop` without a `do`.

Comment: Perhaps you could indent your code more consistently. It would make it easier to fix such bugs.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will work on that. I am still a noob so I appreciate the patience and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't that you had a loop without a do so much as that you had several (I found 3) block `if` statements that were not properly closed with `end if`. At the resulting level of nesting your final `loop` didn't have a `do`. I think that this is what you intended:

```
'Written by Douglas Howe
Option Explicit
Dim colorPicOne, colorPicTwo, tryAgain

'initial do
do
    'first prompt
    do
        Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Pick a primary color (i.e blue, red, or yellow): "
        colorPicOne = lcase(wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
        if colorPicOne <> "blue" and colorPicOne <> "red" and colorPicOne <> "yellow" then
            Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Not a primary color! Please pick another color: "
        else 
            exit do
        end if
    loop while colorPicOne <> "blue" OR colorPicOne <> "red" or colorPicOne <> "yellow"

    'second prompt
    do
        Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Pick another primary color (i.e blue, red, or yellow): "
        colorPicTwo = lcase(wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)
        if colorPicTwo <> "blue" and colorPicTwo <> "red" and colorPicTwo <> "yellow" then
            Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Not a primary color! Please pick another color: "
        else
            exit do
        end if
    loop while colorPicTwo <> "blue" OR colorPicTwo <> "red" or colorPicTwo <> "yellow"

    if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "blue" then
        Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
    else
        if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
            Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
        end if 'This was missing
    end if

    if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "yellow" then
        Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is orange!"
    else
        if colorPicOne = "yellow" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
            Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is orange!"
        end if

        if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo = "yellow" then
            Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is green!"
        else
            if colorPicOne = "yellow" and colorPicTwo ="blue" then
                Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is green!"
            end if 'This was missing
        end if

        Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Would you like to try again? (yes or no) :"
        tryAgain =lcase(Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine)

        if tryAgain = "no" then
            Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Have a nice day"
            exit do
            if tryAgain = "yes" then
                Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Ok!"
            else 
                Wscript.Stdout.WriteLine "Sorry, you gave an invalid response. Good Bye!"
                exit do
            end if 'This was missing
        end if
    end if
loop while tryAgain = "yes"
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The last  "missing" end if was unnecessary though. The code threw out an error

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. The problem is not that you have a `Loop` without a `Do`, but that you have the `Loop` in a place where it doesn't have a preceding `Do` in the same context.

This is the actual reason for the behavior you observed:

```
if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "blue" then
  Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
else
  if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
end if
```

What you probably mean, judging from the indention, is this:

```
if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "blue" then
  Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
else
  if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo ="red" then Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
end if
```

but what you actually have (with proper indention) is this:

```
if colorPicOne = "red" and colorPicTwo = "blue" then
  Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
else
  if colorPicOne = "blue" and colorPicTwo ="red" then
    Wscript.StdOut.Writeline "Your color is purple!"
  end if
end if  '<-- missing "end if" here!
```

Basically, you nested an `If..End If` in the `Else` branch of another `If` expression without closing that `Else` branch. Because of that all subsequent statements are also nested inside that branch, so that the first `Do` and the last `Loop` are in different contexts.

In VBScript you can write `If` expression either like this:

```
If condition Then statement Else other_statement
```

or like this:

```
If condition Then
  statement
Else
  other_statement
End If
```

i.e. if you put `statement` on a new line you *must* close the whole expression with an `End If`. The only exception to this rule is wrapping lines with the line continuation operator (`_`):

```
If condition Then _
  statement
```

The above is valid without `End If`, because it's technically just a single line.